# React native, Android, the warning console from the bottom side appear under navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I don't understand why the warning popup appears under phone's navigation bar. This issue is happening only on android, on Iphone everything is ok.

I am using react-native 0.63 and for navigation I am using react navigation version 5.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the emulator settings as well?

Comment: Hi, @Moistbobo. What do you mean by emulator settings?